How to withdraw from ETH Beacon Staking using privatekey with nodejs or python?
I want to make an automated ETH Staking withdrawal script to schedule it every day.
Is it possible to write an nodejs or python code that make it using privatekey?
Id tried to generate some code with ai but always get errors.
Someone can help me?
Thanks in advance!

Hi, I am a codementor developer and I would like to help you with this.
I have been working on Blockchain Dapps more specifically on Solidity Contracts, Metamask Integration and ethersjs. Happy to get on a call and look into this issue.
